# Promises and pagination in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of events that I'm trying to ng-repeat over. I'm also using UI-Bootstrap to create pagination off of those events. When I hard code that event data into my controller, I am able to display and flip through them no problem. However, when I try to grab that data from a service using promises, my code breaks. I have a feeling it's because I'm not writing my promise correctly (I'm new at them) so when the page loads that data hasn't yet been returned yet.

Here is my controller:

```
App.controller("EventsController", ['$scope', 'EventsService',       function($scope, EventsService) {
  $scope.events = [];
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 5; //items to show per page
  $scope.currentPage = 1;  //what page to start on

  EventsService.getEvents()
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.events = data;
    }, function(error) {
     console.log(error);
  });

  $scope.totalItems = $scope.events.length;

 //determines total # of pages
 $scope.pageCount = function () {
  return Math.ceil($scope.events.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
 };

$scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function() {
  var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
  end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
  $scope.filteredEvents = $scope.events.slice(begin, end);
  });
}]);
```

And my service:

```
App.factory("EventsService", function($http) {
  return {
    getEvents : function() {
      return $http.get("/../../../test_event_data.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        if(typeof response.data === 'object') {
          return response.data;
        } else {
          return $q.reject(response.data);
        }
      }, function(response) {
          return $q.reject(response.data);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And my view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <h3>Filter Results</h3>
    <h3 class="pull-right">All</h3>
    <h3 class="pull-right">Events</h3>
    <h3 class="pull-right">Offerings</h3>
  </div>
 <div class="col-lg-10">
    <h3>Upcoming Events&Offerings</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="event in filteredEvents">
       <h3>{{event.title}}</h3>
       <p>{{event.location}}</p>
       <p>{{event.time}}</p>
       <p>{{event.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
 </div>
</div>
```

Finally, a sample of the data I'm trying to return:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"massa quis augue luctus tincidunt   nulla","location":"Little Fleur","time":"8:33 AM","description":"rhoncus mauris enim leo rhoncus sed vestibulum sit amet cursus id","offering":true},
{"id":2,"title":"sapien ut nunc vestibulum ante","location":"Leroy","time":"6:07 PM","description":"vestibulum proin eu mi nulla ac enim in tempor turpis nec euismod scelerisque quam turpis adipiscing lorem vitae","offering":false},
{"id":3,"title":"sagittis nam congue risus semper porta volutpat","location":"Waubesa","time":"4:13 AM","description":"nisi at nibh in hac habitasse platea dictumst aliquam augue","offering":false},
{"id":4,"title":"consequat ut nulla sed","location":"Dahle","time":"2:08 AM","description":"ligula pellentesque ultrices phasellus id sapien in sapien iaculis congue vivamus metus","offering":false}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

Turns out I needed to put the logic all inside of the getEvents function. So:

```
EventsService.getEvents()
.then(function(data) {
  $scope.events = data;
  $scope.pageCount = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.events.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
  };
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.events.length;
  $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
      end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
    $scope.filteredEvents = $scope.events.slice(begin, end);
  });
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also do the trick:

```
App.controller("EventsController", ['$scope', 'EventsService',       function($scope, EventsService) {
$scope.events = [];
$scope.itemsPerPage = 5; //items to show per page
$scope.currentPage = 1;  //what page to start on

EventsService.getEvents()
.then(function(data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function(value){
       $scope.events.push(value);
     });
 }, function(error) {
     console.log(error);
 });

$scope.pageCount = function () {
   return Math.ceil($scope.events.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
 };
```

Comment: Hmm can't seem to get that to work. $scope.events is not empty inside of the getEvents function, but if I console.log outside $scope.events is empty and I'm unable to display any events in the view. What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: @KyleGiard-Chase at the time the controller is initialized $scope.events is initialized as empty array and getEvents() is called. Then the initialization finishes. Some time later the GetEvents-function is finished and the then-part is called, which fills the $scope.events variable and everything bound to that scope-variable is updated. In your view you only are accessing filteredEvents and not events. Try first to display your list without filtering and then add filtering afterwards.